# What is minimum safe bend radius for rg213?

Tags: coaxial-cable

What is minimum safe bend radius for rg213 cable?

Comment: Check the specs from your supplier. I see several that specify a repeated minimum bend of 1.6" or 42mm. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Once or many times? For RG213 a once-off bend around a 2" diameter cylinder is OK, but if it's a rotator flex loop then you'd want at least a 12" *radius*. The datasheet should give both figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer. One general rule is not bend less than 10 times the diameter of the cable. So a cable that is 0.5 inches in diameter should have a radius of no less than 5 inches.

This for free formed loops. If part of a fixed assembly the bend radius can be less.

Much depends on the type of insulation used. Over time, the center conductor can actually displace the insulation and end up moving toward the shield. This will change the impedance and might eventually lead to a short.

Comment: Minimum radius is not mentioned in the specs for the cable from the supplier I have in mind so these general rules are helpful.